# Noob here. Can I buy a license without installing the software?

Tags: license

I'm not the developer. I have no need for the software on my workstation. I just want to buy the license. Can I buy a license without installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this by yourself... reach out to Pixel & Tonic directly:

> support@craftcms.com

If this software already *is* installed somewhere public, you can simply log in and pay for it directly.